# Having trouble writing a query to pull 1st record from a table

Tags: oracle

I'm using Oracle SQL.

I'm attempting to write a query that queries a table that has employee timecard approval data.  The problem I'm having is on one pay period, an employee has 2 timecard approvals on different dates by different managers (DATASOURCEID).  This is what the table looks like for this person:

```
DATASOURCEID EMPLOYEEID WFCAUDITTYPEID ENTEREDONDTM FROMDTM   TODTM
    2013325  110654     3              4/25/2021    4/11/2021 4/24/2021
    2013618  110654     3              4/26/2021    4/11/2021 4/24/2021
```

I'm using Oracle SQL.

I want to pull the record with the earliest date only.

My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT pe.PERSONFULLNAME AS EmployeeNm, 
       p.personnum AS Employee, 
       l.laborlev2nm AS CCWorked, 
       l.laborlev2dsc AS CCWorkedDesc,  
       pc.PERSONCSTMDATATXT AS Agency,  
       trunc(p.STARTDTM) AS DateIn, 
       to_char(p.STARTDTM,'hh24:mi') AS StartTimeOfDay, 
       trunc(p.ENDDTM) AS DateOut, 
       to_char(p.ENDDTM,'hh24:mi') AS EndTimeOfDay,  
       p.eventdate AS DateWorked, 
       round(sum(t.durationsecsqty/3600.0),2) AS Hours, 
       CC.USERNAME AS SupervisorId,  
       ps.FULLNM AS SupervisorNm, 
       n.abbreviationchar AS PayCode 
FROM tkcsowner.vp_timeshtpunchv42 p 
INNER JOIN tkcsowner.wfctotal t ON t.timesheetitemid = p.timesheetitemid INNER JOIN WFCAUDIT WA on WA.EMPLOYEEID = p.EMPLOYEEID 
      AND t.APPLYDTM between WA.FROMDTM and WA.TODTM 
INNER JOIN DATASOURCE DS ON (WA.DATASOURCEID = DS.DATASOURCEID) 
INNER JOIN CLIENTCONTEXT CC ON (CC.CLIENTCONTEXTID = DS.CLIENTCONTEXTID) 
      AND (CC.USERNAME <> 'Import') 
INNER JOIN tkcsowner.vp_allpersonv42 pe ON pe.EMPLOYEEID = p.EMPLOYEEID 
      AND pe.HOMELABORLEVELNM2 in ('9913', '9914')
LEFT OUTER JOIN tkcsowner.paycode n ON n.paycodeid = t.paycodeid
LEFT OUTER JOIN tkcsowner.laboracct l ON l.laboracctid = t.laboracctid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tkcsowner.PERSON ps ON ps.PERSONNUM = CC.USERNAME 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tkcsowner.personcstmdata pc ON pc.PERSONID = p.PERSONID 
     AND pc.customdatadefid = 6 
WHERE 1 = 1 
AND p.employeeid = 110654 
AND n.NAME in ('ONC-Oncall SBP', 'ONC-Oncall CBP') 
AND (p.startdtm <> p.enddtm) 
AND p.eventdate between '01-FEB-2021' and '31-MAY-2021'
group by pe.PERSONFULLNAME, p.PERSONNUM, l.LABORLEV2NM, l.LABORLEV2DSC, pc.PERSONCSTMDATATXT, p.STARTDTM, p.ENDDTM, p.ENDDTM, p.EVENTDATE, CC.USERNAME, ps.FULLNM, n.ABBREVIATIONCHAR
```

But it's still pulling both records:

```
EMPLOYEENM  EMPLOYEE  DATEIN     DATEOUT   SUPERVISOR  PUNCH          
Bill Dance  110654    4/12/2021  4/13/2021 2013325     ONC
Bill Dance  110654    4/12/2021  4/13/2021 2013618     ONC
```

I left off a few of the columns from the SELECT to make output more readable.

It's pulling the 2 records for same day because they had 2 SUPERVISOR approvals for same pay period.

Any help greatly appreciated!
Thanks, Rufus

Comment: Which database system are you using, Microsoft SQL Server or Oracle SQL?

Comment: J.D. thanks for responding.  I'm using Oracle SQL.

Comment: @RBERTRAND Can you please post the schema for the wfcaudit table?

Comment: Caleb thanks for responding.  I'm not sure how to upload a screen shot of WFCAUDIT table in Schema Viewer.

Comment: ColumnName                 ID     PK    IndexPos    NULL    DataType
DATASOURCEID              1               1, 4            Y           Number (12)
EMPLOYEEID                   2               1, 1            Y           Number (12)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues with your SQL statement:

1. You're applying your aggregate function to the 'employeeid' column, but it's the 'enteredondtm' column that you're trying to find the lowest value one.
2. You're grouping by the `datasourceid` and `enteredondtm` columns - surely you want to find the earliest value in the `enteredondtm` column, and the corresponding `datasourceid` value for that row. If so, you do not want to have these columns in the group by section! (Think of it like: if you had a bucket of balls with numbers on them, and I asked you to find the ball with the lowest number for each colour, you wouldn't separate the balls into groups of colour and number, would you? You would group by colour and then find the lowest number in each group of balls.)
3. I'm assuming that your date columns are of DATE or TIMESTAMP datatypes, and therefore when you compare a date-as-a-string to those columns, you should always explicitly cast that string into a DATE (or TIMESTAMP). If you rely on implicit conversion, as it looks like you're doing with your `12-APRIL-21` (really? 2 digit years? *shudder* - we didn't go through Y2K for nothing, you know!), you're opening yourself up to bugs - what if someone tries running your query on a client that has a different `nls_date_format` setting? It will most likely fail, whereas a correctly converted string-to-date will ensure the query will run on any client.

So, your query could be written like:

```
with wfcaudit as (select 2395711 datasourceid, 110654 employeeid, 3 wfcaudittypeid, to_date('25/04/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') enteredondtm, null  auditdtm, to_date('11/04/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') fromdtm, to_date('24/04/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') todtm from dual union all
                  select 2391965 datasourceid, 110654 employeeid, 3 wfcaudittypeid, to_date('26/04/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') enteredondtm, null  auditdtm, to_date('11/04/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') fromdtm, to_date('24/04/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') todtm from dual)
select wa.employeeid,
       min(wa.datasourceid) keep (dense_rank first order by enteredondtm) datasourceid,
       min(wa.enteredondtm) enteredondtm
from   wfcaudit wa
where  wa.employeeid = 110654
and    to_date('12/04/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') between wa.fromdtm and wa.todtm
group  by wa.employeeid;

EMPLOYEEID DATASOURCEID ENTEREDONDTM
---------- ------------ ------------
    110654      2395711 25/04/2021
```

Note that this query works, but if you wanted to display more than two or three columns, you'd have to apply the `min() keep (dense_rank ...)` function to every column, which gets a bit cumbersome.

Instead, another method is to assign a row number to each row and then filter out just the initial row, e.g.:

```
with wfcaudit as (select 2395711 datasourceid, 110654 employeeid, 3 wfcaudittypeid, to_date('25/04/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') enteredondtm, null  auditdtm, to_date('11/04/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') fromdtm, to_date('24/04/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') todtm from dual union all
                  select 2391965 datasourceid, 110654 employeeid, 3 wfcaudittypeid, to_date('26/04/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') enteredondtm, null  auditdtm, to_date('11/04/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') fromdtm, to_date('24/04/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') todtm from dual),
          res AS (SELECT employeeid,
                         datasourceid,
                         enteredondtm,
                         row_number() OVER (ORDER BY enteredondtm) rn
                  FROM   wfcaudit
                  WHERE  employeeid = 110654
                  and    to_date('12/04/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') between fromdtm and todtm)
SELECT employeeid,
       datasourceid,
       enteredondtm
FROM   res
WHERE  rn = 1;

EMPLOYEEID DATASOURCEID ENTEREDONDTM
---------- ------------ ------------
    110654      2395711 25/04/2021
```

It is arguably easier to understand the intent behind this query, although the first query is more compact.

---

As you have updated your query, but the input data doesn't appear to match the expected output, I'll give you an idea of how you can take your query and apply the logic of either of the queries in my above answer.

You can see that in both of my queries, instead of creating a `wfcaudit` table and populating it with your data, I used a subquery to mimic a table with the data in it. If your data resided in a single table, you wouldn't need that subquery because you would just query the table directly.

It now seems like you have a big, fairly complicated query that generates the data you want to pick the earliest row from, so all you need to do is take that query and put it into a subquery, i.e.:

```
with base_data as (<your query here>)...
```

then you can use that in whichever of the two queries in my answer best suits. I'd go with the second solution myself, so your query would end up looking something like:

```
with base_data as (<your query here>),
  ordered_data as (select <relevant columns>,
                          row_number() over (partition by <column(s) identifying the group, e.g. unique column(s)> -- you can remove the partition by clause if the whole resultset is a single group
                                             order by <whatever column(s) determine the order of the rows in each group>) rn
                   from   base_data)
select <columns>
from   ordered_data
where  rn = 1;
```

Hopefully that is enough for you to generate your own query.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain how it all works together!  I will definitely use on of the examples you've shared.

Comment: Boneist, I should have put the entire query in my original question.  I only put the code I was working on to get it to work.  I edited my original question and have the entire code in it now.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I've edited my answer; hopefully you can use that to write your own query that does what you want.

Comment: Boneist, thanks so much for responding!

I took your recommendations and added them to my query, worked out the errors I was getting, but I have 1 last error that I'm not sure what is wrong, this is the clip that is getting the error:

ordered_data as (select <field names>row_number() over (partition by base_data.ENTEREDONDTM                                              order by base_data.PERSONNUM) rn 
from   base_data)

Comment: Sorry this is the rest of my comment:

select <all columns> 
from ordered_data
where rn = 1

The error is "BASE_DATA"."PERSONNUM" ; invalid identifier
This is on the 'order by line.

Thx!

Comment: If your base_data subquery has `p.personnum AS Employee,` like the query in your question, then you have assigned an alias to the personnum column. That means in your outer query, you need to refer to the column by the alias name. However, it looks like you have got the partition by and order by columns in your analytic function (`row_number()`) the wrong way round - you presumably want to group (aka partition) the rows on by the employee, and since you want to find the earliest row, you would then order by the date column.

Comment: @RBERTRAND I pulled my answer because it's more important that you understand why this works the way that it does, and giving you the exact query will not likely help others as much as this answer will. The concept they and I are offering as the solution is the same. The `ROW_NUMBER()` function identifies the record number from 1-n, seperated by essentially which columns make that row unique, then ordered by the date column you are looking at to get the earliest record. That way rn 1 would be the earliest, rn 2 would be the record that occurred after, and so on.

Comment: Hi Caleb,  Yes I figured out what I needed to do with your help and Boneist examples.  I learned a lot from this interaction, it did take me a little while to figure out the 'partition by' and 'ordered by' functions but it is now working as expected!

A very heartfelt thank you for all your help!

Comment: Hi Boneist,
I figured out what I needed to do with your help and examples.  I learned a lot from this interaction, it did take me a little while to figure out the 'partition by' and 'ordered by' functions but it is now working as expected!

A very heartfelt thank you for all your help!

Comment: Functions that use `partition by` and `order by` are known as analytic functions. They're similar to aggregate functions, except they don't squash the rows. The `partition by` clause works similar to the aggregate `group by` clause. If you omit the `partition by` and order by clauses, e.g. `sum(col) over ()` you get the sum across all rows output for every row. If you had a `partition by` clause, you'd get the sum across all rows in each group. Adding an `order by` clause gives you a cumulative sum across each group. Some analytic functions must have an `order by` clause (e.g. `row_number()`)

Comment: They also allow you apply the function to windows of data (and so they are sometimes known as windowing functions), e.g. moving averages, etc, by using the `range between` or `rows between` clauses.

Comment: Boneist, thatnks for the perfect explanation on analytic functions.  I don't use them very often, this might be the 2nd or 3rd time.  I feel much more confident now if I have to use them in the future!

Thanks again!
Rufus